# Displaying iframe inside div

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, iframe

I want to display the iframe inside a div. I want to display the data inside the iframe. So I've tried like this:

nav-bar.php:

```
  <li class="dropdown">
    <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#" title="Report">Report<span class="caret"></span></a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li>
        <a href="content.php?report=list" target="iframe_report">Dashboard</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
```

report.php:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <?php include("heading.php"); ?>
</head>
<body role="document">
  <?php include("includes/inc-header.php"); ?>
    <div class="panel-body">
      <div class="col-sm-12">
         <iframe id="iframe_report" name="iframe_report" style="border:dotted; width:100%; height:450px;"></iframe>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

content.php:

```
<?php
    include("configuration.php");
    $report = $_GET["report"];
    $title = $_GET["title"];
    $pagetitle = $title;
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <?php include("heading.php"); ?>
</head>
<body role="document">
  <?php include("nav-bar.php"); ?>
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        <?php echo $title; ?>
          <input type="hidden" id="input" name="input" value="<?php echo $report; ?>">
       </div>
       <div class="panel-body">
         <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" id="table_list" class="table table-striped table-bordered hide">
           <thead>
             <tr>
               <th></th>
               <th>Name</th>
               <th>List</th>
             </tr>
           </thead>
           <tbody>
           </tbody>
         </table>
       </div>
  </div>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
  jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
    var input_report = jQuery("#input").val();
    var table_id = "#table_report_" + input;
    jQuery(table_id).removeClass("hide").addClass("show");

    jQuery(table_id).DataTable({
      paging: false,
      select: true,
      ajax: "reports-db.php?report=" + input_report,
    });
  });
</script>
```

This is how I tried. When I click the option in the nav-bar, the data should be fetched and displayed in the same page. But, what happens is, when I click the option, it opens in the new page. But, I want to display it in the same page and all the nav-bar options should also be displayed. I've want it in such a way that, the nav-bar should be displayed and below that there lies a div, inside which the iframe should be displayed. But, don't know what's redirecting it to the new window. Can someone guide me?

Comment: is this question anyway related to html and css? you tags are probably wrong. please use proper tags while asking question. i think php, javascript should be the tags you should be using

Comment: I agree with your comment.  Also, @duddosai can you give us more information on your structure?  Nav-bar is obvious but how are report.php and content.php related?

Comment: report.php is the place where I have placed the div and my iframe inside the div. content.php is the place where I've placed the table that should be displayed inside the iframe.

Comment: @Lucian Thanks for your suggestion bro.

Comment: @duddosai The iframe will contain a table of reports right?

Comment: Unless things have moved on rapidly, iFrames need a source file (src=...). I suggest that either your iframe src file loads the necessary php file to construct your table, or your src file is a blank html file and you then build its innerHTML from onload function in the main page.

Comment: @TonyDuffill. src is the source from where the data comes into the iframe right? I tried using that but, it still opens in the new window. This is how I tried. I put src="content.php" in the iframe tag.

Comment: @duddosai - Yes, that's what I do. But the rest of your parent page will also need to be correct - working with iframes can be tricky - it took me a while. Bear in mind that your content.php file needs to be totally self-contained, you are opening a separate file in a separate window - and that the iframe src file won't load until the whole parent page has loaded successfully.

I suggest reading up on iframes and maybe start with a static html file as the src file while you play around with the rest of the page.